Asymptotic behavior of Hermite polynomials and Hermite functions evaluated at a point
I would like to understand the asymptotic behavior of the Hermite polynomials $H_m(x)$ at a fixed point $x=x_0\in\mathbb{R}$. For instance, I am trying to prove if $$\frac{H_m(x_0)}{\sqrt{2^m m!}}\sim  O\big(m^p\big),$$ with suitable $p\in \mathbb{R}$ and for $x_0\neq 0$. This asymptotics will help me to understand if
$$I_m=\int_{x_0}^{+\infty} \psi_m(x) \psi_0(x) dx\sim O\big(m^q\big),$$
where $\psi_m$ are the Hermite (normalized) functions and $q\in\mathbb{R}$. Thank you in advance!

Note that for your second problem, one requires an asymptotics that is uniform in $x$. The one I provided below is not of that type.

Your conjectured asymptotic form is indeed correct with the optimal value $p=-\frac{1}{4}$. Using $(18.15.27)$ and Stirling's formula, try to show that as $m\to+\infty$ with any fixed $x\in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\frac{{H_{2m} (x)}}{{\sqrt {2^{2m} (2m)!} }} = \frac{{( - 1)^m }}{{(\pi m)^{1/4} }}{\rm e}^{\frac{1}{2}x^2 } \left( {\cos \left( {\sqrt {4m + 1}\, x} \right) + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt m }}} \right)} \right)
$$
and
$$
\frac{{H_{2m + 1} (x)}}{{\sqrt {2^{2m + 1} (2m + 1)!} }} = \frac{{( - 1)^m }}{{(\pi m)^{1/4} }}{\rm e}^{\frac{1}{2}x^2 } \left( {\sin \left( {\sqrt {4m + 3} \,x} \right) + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt m }}} \right)} \right).
$$

Are these formulas enough to conclude that for certain points as $x=a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ we have
$$\psi_k(a)\sim k^{-p},$$ with $p>0$? For me, it is actually enough to show that
$$\psi_k(a)\gtrsim k^{-p}.$$

These asymptotics are for fixed $x$. You will not be able to integrate them to infinity to get an asymptotics for the integrals. You may also define $\psi_k$.
